# Powershell return string found

Tags: powershell

I used Select-String to find a substring I don't understand : it seems to return the whole parent string or nothing am I wrong ?

If I'm not, that's not what I want : I want the string from the position it found. Is there a standard function for that or should I craft my own ?

Answer (score 1):

If we inspect the data a little more closely, we find that `Select-String` outputs a `MatchInfo` object containing the line, *as well as information about the matched substring*:

```
PS C:\> "string" |Select-String "." |Get-Member

   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

The `Matches` property is what we'll want here:

```
$string  = "Hello there, user3101291!"
$pattern = "user\d+"

$result = $string |Select-String -Pattern $pattern |Select -First 1

# this will give us only the actually matched part of the string
$result.Matches.Value
```

---

Another option is the use the `-match` operator along with the `$Matches` automatic variable:

```
$string  = "Hello there, user3101291!"
$pattern = "user\d+"

if($string -match $pattern){
    # 0 = whole matched substring
    $Matches[0]
}
```

The cool thing about `$Matches`, besides it's simplicity, is that it support capture groups as well, do we can get even more granular:

```
$string  = "Hello there, user3101291!"
$pattern = "user(?<numberPart>\d+)"

if($string -match $pattern){
    # 0 = whole matched substring
    $Matches[0]

    # 1 = first group
    $Matches[1]

    # But we can extract groups by name as well
    $Matches['numberPart']
}
```